# Is it common practice to put code documentation under version control?

Tags: git, version-control, repository, doxygen

I have a github repository and I have recently noticed that the documentation (which got created via doxygen) has also been uploaded to the repo, because it is in the same folder as the source code.

Now my question: is it common practice to do this, to also provide the documentation (html, latex) in the repo?

Answer (score 1):

#### "Compiled" documentation

I guess that's the case, since you mentioned doxygen.

If you build the documentation automatically there is no reason to put it under version control (for the same reason you don't put compiled binaries under version control).

It's often advisable to ignore the folder where the documentation gets built (i.e. `repository/doc_build`), by creating a `.gitignore` file in the root of the repository with this line:

```
doc_build/
```

This will prevent pushing that folder accidentally.

#### Source code of documentation

On the other hand, if a project writes code documentation in a markup language (like Markdown, reStructuredText, and so on), then it makes sense to put the documentation's source code under version control.

It makes sense because in that way you have a single place to collaborate with others on the documentation (in addition to collaborating on the code). Often a change to the code implies a change to the documentation: in this way you can do these changes in a single commit.

There are even services like *readthedocs.org* for hosting your documentation which allow you to import it from github (and automatically rebuild it when you change it from github).

As an example of that, this github project keeps the documentation under version control (and also provides a compiled version):

- https://github.com/cms-dev/cms/tree/master/docs -- documentation folder under version control
- https://cms.readthedocs.org -- the (automatically) compiled version